# How to use same function with different multiple inputs name to shorten the code in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I create a shinyApp to generate multiple ggplot, and I define the universal function, `labs_custom`, `theme_custom`, to allow users to change the outlook of the plot, how can I shorten the code? Because the difference of the content is only the plot type.

```
bar <- reactive({
  p <- plot_bar(bar_data, input$bar_position, input$bar_dodge_type, input$bar_x, input$bar_x_multi, input$bar_fill_multi, input$bar_alpha, input$bar_width, input$bar_linewidth, input$bar_padding, input$bar_colour, input$bar_errorbar, input$bar_errorbar_width, input$bar_errorbar_shape, input$bar_errorbar_colour, input$bar_jitter, input$bar_jitter_width, input$bar_jitter_size, input$bar_jitter_colour)
  p <- p + labs_custom(input$bar_labs_title, input$bar_labs_subtitle, input$bar_labs_caption, input$bar_labs_tag, input$bar_labs_x, input$bar_labs_y)
  p <- p + theme_custom(
    input$bar_axis.title.x_family, input$bar_axis.title.x_face, input$bar_axis.title.x_colour, input$bar_axis.title.x_size, input$bar_axis.title.x_hjust, input$bar_axis.title.x_angle, input$bar_axis.title.y_family, input$bar_axis.title.y_face, input$bar_axis.title.y_colour, input$bar_axis.title.y_size, input$bar_axis.title.y_hjust, input$bar_axis.title.y_angle,
    input$bar_plot.title_family, input$bar_plot.title_face, input$bar_plot.title_colour, input$bar_plot.title_size, input$bar_plot.title_hjust, input$bar_plot.title_angle,
    input$bar_plot.subtitle_family, input$bar_plot.subtitle_face, input$bar_plot.subtitle_colour, input$bar_plot.subtitle_size, input$bar_plot.subtitle_hjust, input$bar_plot.subtitle_angle,
    input$bar_plot.caption_family, input$bar_plot.caption_face, input$bar_plot.caption_colour, input$bar_plot.caption_size, input$bar_plot.caption_hjust, input$bar_plot.caption_angle,
    input$bar_plot.tag_family, input$bar_plot.tag_face, input$bar_plot.tag_colour, input$bar_plot.tag_size, input$bar_plot.tag_hjust, input$bar_plot.tag_angle
  )
  return(p)
})

volcano <- reactive({
  p <- plot_volcano(volcano_data, input$volcano_pthreshold, input$volcano_fcthreshold, input$volcano_point_alpha, input$volcano_point_size, input$volcano_point_up, input$volcano_point_down, input$volcano_point_ns, input$volcano_assist_lines, input$volcano_hline_linetype, input$volcano_hline_color, input$volcano_vline_linetype, input$volcano_vline_color)
  p <- p + labs_custom(input$volcano_labs_title, input$volcano_labs_subtitle, input$volcano_labs_caption, input$volcano_labs_tag, input$volcano_labs_x, input$volcano_labs_y)
  p <- p + theme_custom(
    input$volcano_axis.title.x_family, input$volcano_axis.title.x_face, input$volcano_axis.title.x_colour, input$volcano_axis.title.x_size, input$volcano_axis.title.x_hjust, input$volcano_axis.title.x_angle,
    input$volcano_axis.title.y_family, input$volcano_axis.title.y_face, input$volcano_axis.title.y_colour, input$volcano_axis.title.y_size, input$volcano_axis.title.y_hjust, input$volcano_axis.title.y_angle,
    input$volcano_plot.title_family, input$volcano_plot.title_face, input$volcano_plot.title_colour, input$volcano_plot.title_size, input$volcano_plot.title_hjust, input$volcano_plot.title_angle,
    input$volcano_plot.subtitle_family, input$volcano_plot.subtitle_face, input$volcano_plot.subtitle_colour, input$volcano_plot.subtitle_size, input$volcano_plot.subtitle_hjust, input$volcano_plot.subtitle_angle,
    input$volcano_plot.caption_family, input$volcano_plot.caption_face, input$volcano_plot.caption_colour, input$volcano_plot.caption_size, input$volcano_plot.caption_hjust, input$volcano_plot.caption_angle,
    input$volcano_plot.tag_family, input$volcano_plot.tag_face, input$volcano_plot.tag_colour, input$volcano_plot.tag_size, input$volcano_plot.tag_hjust, input$volcano_plot.tag_angle
  )
  return(p)
})
```

Comment: Please check shiny's [modules](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/modules/).

Comment: Modules are a sensible suggestion. But functions are R objects, just like data frames. So you could create an argument to your function, `geom_func`, say, and pass the relevant geom using that.

Comment: In the end modules are also just a pair of functions with a dedicated namespace. Both approaches are fine - but on the long run familiarizing with modules will help regarding the maintainability of larger apps. Cheers

Comment: PS: in your function you can access the inputs just like a list: use `input[[variable]]` instead of `input$name` (guess that is the reason for your question?)

Comment: sorry, can you give me a minimal example, I can define functions, but never use the modules.